# how to split and rename objects inside a list in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, maya

I have to grab all the objects with _cnt in my maya scene and split up them to obtain 
from this :

```
#Left_Hand_Cnt
```

to this :

```
#Left_Hand_001_cnt
```

I've written this little script but only works with the first object.

```
cnt = cmds.select ('*_cnt*')
cnts = cmds.ls (sl=True)        
new = cnts[0].split("_")
cmds.rename (new[0] + "_" + new[1] + "_" + "001" + "_" + new[2])
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to do something to the first object, you can do the same thing to *each* object with a `for` loop:

```
for cnt in cnts:
    new = cnt.split("_")
    modified = new[0] + "_" + new[1] + "_" + "001" + "_" + new[2]
```

---

So, you can do anything you want with `modified` within that `for` loop. For example:

```
for cnt in cnts:
    new = cnt.split("_")
    modified = new[0] + "_" + new[1] + "_" + "001" + "_" + new[2]
    os.rename(cnt, modified)
```

But if you want to build a new list to keep around, you're probably better off using a list comprehension (or the `map` function):

```
def modify_cnt(cnt):
    new = cnt.split("_")
    return new[0] + "_" + new[1] + "_" + "001" + "_" + new[2]

modified_cnts = [modify_cnt(cnt) for cnt in cnts]
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend "new" as an identifier, even though it's not a Python keyword.  Programmers with experience in other languages may find that quite distracting if they are trying to maintain your code later.

Additionally you haven't shown how to modify the original list or build a new list of these modified results.

Comment: @JimDennis: The `new` comes from the OP's code. And the OP isn't trying to modify the original list, or build a new one, he's trying to use each modified entry in a function.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I'm not trying to show the OP a better way to do the part he already knows how to do, I'm trying to show him how to do it in a loop. I think replacing his existing logic will just confuse him—and it's not what he asked for. But that's useful as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

More robust solution:

```
lines = """
#Left_Hand_Cnt
#bla_bla_bla_not
#bla_bla_bla_Cnt
"""

for line in lines.splitlines():
    flds = line.split("_")
    if flds[-1].lower()=="cnt":
        print "%s_%03d_%s" % ("_".join(flds[:-1]), 1, flds[-1])
```

Output:

```
#Left_Hand_001_Cnt
#bla_bla_bla_001_Cnt
```